# HIghcharts seperation of legend and pie

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts

I am developing an application and i need the data in the pie to be displayed in an *ascending order* 
The chart has a legend ..

[heres](http://jsfiddle.net/kodeNinja/kTXNQ/) the fiddle

What i need is the data in the pie should be shown from smallest to greatest whereas the legend should maintain its state ..

100-200 ..
200-300 ..
..and so on ..

Is that possible without having to seperately create the legend ..

Comment: Isn't the data already ascending in the pie? It starts with 100-200 at 12 o'clock and then ascending in clockwise direction. Or do you want to sort by the value (percentage browser share) ascending?

Comment: I want to sort the pie by value without affecting the legend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When [passing the series](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data), you can also give complete objects instead of datapoints and labels only. These objects also have a `legendIndex` property where you can specify the exact position in the legend.

Now when you give the series, you have to manually sort it by the value ascending. This will arrange the pie chart in ascending order, and with the legend index it will also keep the legend in order.

[Updated JSfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/gnCSY/).